Confused about the statement: "Continuous linear functional on $(X^∗, weak^∗)$ are just evaluations at some point of X."
I was going through the answer to this question. I confused with the following statement of the answer provided there: $$(*) ``\text{Continuous linear functional on $(X^∗, weak^∗)$  are just evaluations at some point of X.}"$$
I know that the elements of $X^{**}$(topological dual of $X^*$) are all the continuous linear functionals on $X^*$. Also, I know that if an element of $X^{**}$ is weak* continuous then it is of the form $\psi_x$ for some $x\in X$, where $\psi$ is the canonical embedding from $X$ into $X^{**}$. Now, in particular, I have the following follow-up queries:

Does every element of $X^{**}$ is a evaluation at some point of $X$?
If so, then is the canonical embedding a special kind of evaluation? I am confused about the evaluation maps and canonical embedding.
If the above statement $(*)$ is right, can anyone please explain it in detail?

Where am I wrong? Please help me. Any help is appreciated.

Continuous linear functional on $(X^∗, weak^∗)$ are not the same as  Continuous linear functional on $(X^∗, |.|)$. The answer to 1) is NO.

Thank you for your comment. Continuous linear functionals on $(X^, weak^)$ are weak* continuous right? But in norm case it may not be.
